# Mysql Query Listing Comments With It's Replies

Tags: coalesce

I am creating a comment with reply box. With this table 'comments', how do I write a query to have it list the parent comment first(id), follow by the replies(replyTo) if any below its parent comment.

In this example, I want to list the rows in this order.

87 - comment
86 - comment
88 - reply to 86

I tried using this query, but it is listing the reply first than its parent comment.

88
86
87

```
$q_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$database['prefix']."comments
                         WHERE postid = '$b_post'
                         ORDER BY COALESCE (replyTo,id) DESC
                         ") or die(mysql_error());   



id  postid  reply   name    email
86  67      0       don     xxx
87  67      0       larry   xxx
88  67      86      duc     xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figure it out why it wasn't working. When using 'COALESCE', the column(replyTo) needed to be set to NULL and not '0'.